# Babel won't use plugin

Tags: react-native, babeljs, docz

So, I've been having for a while this persistent error and it's driving me nuts. I'm trying to build with docz the documentation for my project, but it's raising the following error:

> %AppDirectory%\node_modules\react-native-vector-icons\lib\create-icon-set.js: Support for the experimental syntax 'classProperties' isn't currently enabled

It tells me to install and use either @babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties or @babel/plugin-syntax-class-properties. Then again, my Babel project-wide config file is:

```
module.exports = {
  presets: ['module:metro-react-native-babel-preset'],
  env: {
    test: {
      plugins: [
          'react-native-config-node/transform',
          ['@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties', {"loose": true}]
      ],
    },
    
    dev: {
        plugins: [
            'react-native-config-node/transform',
            ['@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties', {"loose": true}]
        ]
    }
  },
};
```

Then again, with either this config or one with plugin-syntax-class-properties, the error persists. I've also tried to use the path to the plugin, as per [the docs](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/plugins), to no avail. Can someone help me with this? Thanks beforehand